# What are the reasons for the end of the dogfight era?

Tags: military, fighter, dogfighting, aerial-combat

A lot of sources mention that a lot of modern era (5.Gen) fighter jet designs such as the F-35 are focussing on qualities and properties such as stealth, long-range attacks, and versatility just to name a few. It is often brought up that the era of dogfights is over. What was the reason for this shift of desirable qualities in air defense and combat?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14952/62)

Comment: I thought about asking if the era is really over as a new question. Many experts thought that the era was over before the Vietnam war, but experience rapidly proved those experts wrong. So maybe history is repeating itself, and experts who predict that the era is over now are wrong; maybe in the near future autonomous drones will change everything. Anyway, it occurs to me that it would be better to edit your question to also ask if the era is really definitely over, rather than to ask a new question that may be flagged as a duplicate. If you agree please feel free to edit your question.

Comment: This has been debated many times on similar questions such as the one linked above.  I'm voting to close.

Comment: Or maybe the whole thing is just a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily this was driven by the invention of the guided missile which can be deployed far outside the range of bullets (making them a *standoff weapon*) and which can actively track the target autonomously ("shoot and forget").

With these two features, it no longer became necessary to maneuver close enough to another plane to shoot it down with bullets and to accurately track the target aircraft with one's own aircraft while doing so- which made WWI and WWII dogfighting skills unnecessary.

Comment: I beg to differ.  So does the US Military.

Comment: @MichaelHall, why not post your own answer? then I'll delete mine.

Comment: There are a bunch of great answers and discussions on the other linked question. This is a dupe, not worth rehashing in my opinion.